# c# How to get Listbox selection from Observable Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I'm probably not even asking this correctly, I am new to c#, but trying to help my 14 year-old son learn.  I've created a listbox with items created with an ObservableCollection.  Here is the XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="105,205,886,63"
   IsTabStop="True" SelectionChanged="PrintText" 
   ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" TabIndex="5" FontSize="36" 
   Background="Transparent" Foreground="#FF55B64C" FontFamily="Arabic Typesetting" 
   FontWeight="Bold" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" SelectionMode="Single" >
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Name="blockNameList" Text="{Binding name}"/>
                <TextBlock Text=" #"/>
                <TextBlock Name="blockIdList" Text="{Binding id}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
</ListBox>
```

Here is how I created the ListBox Items:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var uri = new Uri("http://theurlImusing");
Stream respStream2 = await client.GetStreamAsync(uri);
// DataContractJsonSerializer ser2 = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));
// RootObject feed2 = (RootObject)ser2.ReadObject(respStream2);
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = null;
ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<RootObject>));
ObservableCollection<RootObject> feed2 = ser.ReadObject(respStream2) as ObservableCollection<RootObject>;

var cardList = new List<RootObject>();

foreach (RootObject returnfeed in feed2)
{
    string cid = returnfeed.id;
    string cardname = returnfeed.name;
    listBox1.Items.Add(new RootObject { id=cid, name=cardname });
}
```

I thought I would just use the SelectionChanged="PrintText" property of the listbox so that when I clicked on a listbox item, it would just change a textblock's text value.  Ultimately, that is all I am trying to do...set a textblock or textbox to be equal to the "id" value that is clicked on in the ListBox.

```
void PrintText(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
     //What do I put in here??    
}
```

Thanks very much for any insight!  I need it!!

Comment: A quick note... you should either bind the `ItemsSource` property of the ListBox to an `ObservableCollection` of items, or you should add items to the `ListBox.Items` collection manually. Do not do both. But you probably are looking for `listBox1.SelectedItem`, and cast it as a `RootObject`

Comment: A good point - I think he was trying to modify the items in the `RootObject` collection prior to binding, though, it looks like, to me.  But yeah, you wouldn't set up things with a custom `listBox1.Items.Add` line as well as setting `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` and `Text="{Binding name}"` and `Text="{Binding id}"` in the `DataTemplate`.  Should do one or the other.  You don't have to do `listBox1.Items.Add` if you bind to a filled `ObservableCollection`, such as `feed2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something that is much easier to do using data binding.  You can bind the `TextBlock.Text` property directly to the `ListBox` using an `ElementName` binding:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=listBox1,Path=SelectedItem.id}" />
```

Alternatively, if you set set `SelectedValuePath="id"` on the ListBox, then binding to `SelectedValue` will give you the "id" property:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox1" SelectedValuePath="id" ... />
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=listBox1,Path=SelectedValue}" />
```

---

As a side note (as @Rachel already noted in comments): you may as well just set the `ItemsSource`, rather than looping through and adding each manually.  All you need is this:

```
listBox1.ItemsSource = feed2;
```

**Edit**

Ok, if you wanted to use the procedural approach, here's how you would do it.  (No one would recommend this approach, especially if you're learning/teaching.  Try to make full use of data binding, and view-viewmodel separation.)

```
void PrintText(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var listBox = (ListBox)sender;
    RootObject selectedItem = listBox.SelectedItem;
    someTextBox.Text = selectedItem.id;
}
```

Comment: Thank you McGarnagle and Rachel for the help and insight!  I ended up just putting that "{Binding ElementName=listBox1,Path=SelectedItem.id}" in the XAML and that did the trick.  I also removed the loop that added the items manually and just bound to ItemSource.  I can't say I fully understand all of it, but this gives me enough to take a step back and dive a bit deeper.  Really appreciate the help!  Happy Holidays to all!!

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is click an item in the ListBox and get it to show up in the TextBox, you don't need fancy binding (in that other answer) to do it.  You can simply add a `MouseUp` event in the `ListBox` XAML:

```
MouseUp="ListBox1_MouseUp"
```

This would work similar to the `SelectionChanged` event you wanted to use.

You then right-click that function name in the XAML page and select "Go to definition".  It will create the next function for you:

```
private void ListBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Simply add in there to update the TextBox you want with the `SelectedItem` values from `sender`:

```
private void ListBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox lstBox = (ListBox)sender;
    ListBoxItem item = lstBox.SelectedItem;

    if (item != null)  // avoids exception when an empty line is clicked
    {
        someBox.Text = item.name;
        someOtherBox.Text = item.id;
    }
}
```

I later found that `blockNameList` and `blockIdList` are not accessible via intellisense because they are within the DataTemplate of the ListBox, so I put `someBox` and `someOtherBox`, as references to other TextBoxes you would have to add to the XAML, outside of the ListBox.  You would not re-write data inside the ListBox on the same item by clicking it.  Even if you could reach the template's TextBlock to do it, you'd just be re-writing that same item with its own values, since it would be the `SelectedItem`!

Even though there are those that don't recommend this approach because they like binding everything - and in some cases you want binding to occur so that controls on the page update as a result of dependencies (i.e. do one thing to cause another), I find that manual methods of clicking a button/item/control to update something are just fine and avoid all the model/MVVM BS that has taken over WPF and over-complicated it.